# Cannot upload thumbnail to an Amazon S3 target bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have recently started to learn AWS. I am following the AWS tutorial using AWS lambda with Amazon S3. I have followed most of the steps correctly but the problem occurs when I am trying to get the thumbnail of the image from my source bucket to the resized bucket.
I am using the AWS-CLI command

```
aws lambda invoke --function-name thumbnail-s3 --invocation-type RequestResponse --payload file://inputFile.txt --cli-binary-format raw-in-base64-out outputFile.txt
```

and I am getting a

```
{
    "StatusCode": 200,
    "ExecutedVersion": "$LATEST"
}
```

which means that execution is successful, but when I check my s3 resized bucket I don't see the thumbnail. could anyone please help me figure this out?

Comment: Can you add any debugging, then check in CloudWatch logs? Validate that it is even hitting the code you expect it to

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to guess what has happened with just function invocation and response. You could add more debug logs in your s3 upload function to get more details.
How to access cloudwatch logs for lambda:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/monitoring-cloudwatchlogs.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/troubleshooting-execution.html